# Ĉu “trapasi ekzamenon” signifas ke oni sukcesis je ĝi?

Tags: word-meaning

Ĉu *trapasi ekzamenon* signifas ke oni sukcesis aŭ nur ke oni ĉeestis kaj partoprenis, sen diri ion ajn pri la rezulto?

La angla kaj la franca havas similajn esprimojn, sed laŭ mia kompreno ili ne havas la saman signifon.

- *passer un examen* signifas nur ke oni ĉeestis, kaj oni dirus *réussir un examen* por paroli pri sukceso
- *pass an exam* signifas ke oni sukcesis, kaj oni diras *take an exam* por la alia senco.

Mi kredas ke la fama [kanto de JoMo](https://youtu.be/8qQolY9h9a0) uzas ĝin kun la franca senco, sed la regularo de la KER-ekzameno mem ŝajne uzas ĝin kun la angla senco:

> Ĉe ekzameno B2 la minimumaj priplenumaj poento-nombroj por trapasi ekzamenon, por 
>   ĉiu respektiva kapablo estas:

Answer (score 3):

Mia impreso estas, ke se oni diras *trapasi ekzamenon* sen aldona klarigo, tio signifas ke oni sukcesis ĉe la ekzameno (se la kunteksto ne indikas kontraŭe). Kutime oni nuancas: *bone trapasi*, *sukcese trapasi*, ktp. Laŭ la Granda Vortaro Hispana-Esperanta *trapasi ekzamenon* signifas *sukcesi ĉe ekzameno*.

Mi tamen opinias, ke por eviti dubon aŭ konfuzon oni uzu ian rimedon (ekz. nuancon, kuntekston, ktp.) por klarigi la sencon. Se la intenco estas simple esprimi, ke oni faris ekzamenon sen indiko de (mal)sukceso, oni simple diru *fari ekzamenon*.